# how to extract text value using jsoup

Tags: jsoup, selectors-api

I am trying to extract a text value that comes right after CheckBoxIsChecked="t"

```
p  > w|Sdt[CheckBoxIsChecked$='t']
```

but it seems like jsoup is ignoring it, I am not sure how to read the text that comes after this
I can do it using java but I am trying to make it generic
is there something like:

```
p  > w|Sdt[CheckBoxIsChecked$='t']  > first text after...
```

in this example the value needed is:
 **I Need this value since CheckBoxIsChecked is true**

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal">
<w:Sdt CheckBox="t" CheckBoxIsChecked="t" >
    <span style="font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;">y</span>
</w:Sdt> I Need this value since CheckBoxIsChecked is true 
<w:Sdt CheckBox="t" CheckBoxIsChecked="f" >
    <span style="font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;">n</span>
</w:Sdt> This is not needed since CheckBoxIsChecked is false 
<w:Sdt CheckBox="t" CheckBoxIsChecked="f">
    <span style="font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;">n</span>
</w:Sdt> This is not needed since CheckBoxIsChecked is false<o:p/>
```

[link to the sample](http://try.jsoup.org/~Hji0wCTnOg5CnGhKtee8dedwArQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element.ownText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) method to extract text laying next to specific tag. Below you can find an example created based on your example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\">\n" +
                "<w:Sdt CheckBox=\"t\" CheckBoxIsChecked=\"t\" >\n" +
                "    <span style=\"font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;\">y</span>\n" +
                "</w:Sdt> I Need this value since CheckBoxIsChecked is true \n" +
                "<w:Sdt CheckBox=\"t\" CheckBoxIsChecked=\"f\" >\n" +
                "    <span style=\"font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;\">n</span>\n" +
                "</w:Sdt> This is not needed since CheckBoxIsChecked is false \n" +
                "<w:Sdt CheckBox=\"t\" CheckBoxIsChecked=\"f\">\n" +
                "    <span style=\"font-family:&quot;MS Gothic&quot;\">n</span>\n" +
                "</w:Sdt> This is not needed since CheckBoxIsChecked is false<o:p/>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        doc.select("p > w|sdt[checkboxischecked=t]").forEach(it -> {
            String text = it.ownText();
            System.out.println(text);
        });

    }
}
```

Here you can run <kbd>[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/5DY)</kbd>